# wp_mail attachements does not work

Tags: php, wordpress, attachment

I tried to use wp_mail with attachments, but I cannot receive any attachments. Please help

```
$attachments = get_user_meta($userID, 'resume_pdf', true);

if ($attachments != '') {
  wp_mail($to,$subject,$msg,$headers,$attachments);
  $msg .= '<br><br>' . $attachments;
} else{
  wp_mail($to,$subject,$msg,$headers);
}
```

what saved as resume_pdf is something like this:
http://aiprojectlink.com/wp-content/uploads/userpro/1/560387d6eaa3b.pdf

I think it should be the full path, I can open the link directly by clicking it, but there is no attachment.
Please help, thank you.

Comment: First try `echo $attachments; die();` after `$attachments = get_user_meta($userID, 'resume_pdf', true);` and let me know what is outputing.

Answer (score 0):

See [examples](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail#Examples) from [wp_mail](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail).

`$attachments` should be **path** or array of **paths**. Not url.

Example from Codex:

```
$attachments = array( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/file_to_attach.zip' );
$headers = 'From: My Name <myname@example.com>' . "\r\n";
wp_mail( 'test@example.org', 'subject', 'message', $headers, $attachments );
```